# How to transpose selected data from Tab delimited file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, csv

I have a input files with **3 columns** each-

```
File1 -     SNP    SampleID    Pairs (header)
            rs1     sample1    AG
            rs1     sample2    GT
            rs1     sample3    AG
            rs2     sample1    AG
            rs2     sample2    TT
            rs2     sample3    GG
            rs3     sample1    GG
            rs3     sample2    AG
            rs3     sample3    AG
```

Expected output file- kind of matrix with all SNPs in row and sample ids in columns

```
example:    
     sample1    sample2    sample3 .........
rs1   AG          GT          AG
rs2   AG          TT          GG
rs3   GG          AG          AG
```

The input file is a tab separated one and the output file should also be a tab separated one.

The solution can be in Java.
Edit: I can read the file but not sure how to write it in another file in the given format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem here, you don't know how to read a file in Java or Perl? for Java you could use the (Apache common-csv)[https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html] lib. The link is a guide on how to use it. In your case set the tab `\t` char as separator.

Comment: Apologies for the inaccurate info. I know how to read a tab separated file, but I am not able to figure out how to print it in a tab separated file in the given format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To printout a String separated by tag, check out this code:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%s\t%s", "a", "b","c"));
```

You just need to put `\t` as separator, as this char is a `tab`, when you print out your result.

If you use a StringBuffer to concatenate the row, you could use the char instead the string:

```
'\t'
```

And not:

```
"\t"
```

[Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/) you could find a more detailed guide on how to read/write a CSV file.